# Line break in multipart rectangle node with align specification

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to ask how I can add a line break in a multipart rectangle node.

Code that I've written should work but it is not. Can you tell me what I have done wrong, or how can I tune it to make it work.

```
\tikzstyle{umlclass}=[
    draw=black,
    fill=yellow!16,
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts = 3,
    rectangle split part align={center,left,left},
    execute at begin node = \ttfamily,
]   
\node[umlclass]{
    <<interface>>\\
    class
    \nodepart{second}
    +attribute
};
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I would consider using the [`tikz-uml`](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en) package: is not available on CTAN, but it could be of help for your purpose.

Comment: no it's not, there is lot of sheity thinks. Most importat is that it wont iplements shapes and styles.

Comment: @wikingun: actually I don't know anything about uml, but I've looked at the code and, from a TikZ point of view, you can define your own styles via `\tikzumlset`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use a `\parbox`. You still could use `\centering` for the alignment, if desired. Furthermore it's recommended to use `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{umlclass/.style={
    draw=black,
    fill=yellow!16,
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts = 3,
    rectangle split part align={center,left,left},
    execute at begin node = \ttfamily,
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[umlclass]{
    \parbox{2.4cm}{\centering
      <<interface>>\\
      class}
    \nodepart{second}
    +attribute
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: UML node]

The very good comment of egreg, to use a tabular to not need to know the width:

```
\node[umlclass]{
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      <<interface>>\\
      class
    \end{tabular}
    \nodepart{second}
    +attribute
};
```

[image: UML node]

Comment: Or a `tabular`, that avoids the need to guess the width.

Comment: stefab do you see that class is LEFT aligned?

Comment: Is not what i wanted, but it is also helpful

Comment: @egreg or I just handrite it ?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of improving the tabular; defining `\newcommand{\splitpart}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}` may be even better.

Comment: @egreg Feel free, always :-) Btw. I meant the vertical spacing with tabular, originally.

Comment: You should consider that tabular added, aditional space around tabuler, but it is good, but stil sheeity solution. THX

Comment: The vertical spacing problem can be solved by using lower level commands: `\newcommand{\splitpart}[1]{\vbox{\let\\=\cr\halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr#1\crcr}}}`

Answer (score 5):

You have to supply `align=center` to the general `node` options, as the first node part isn't treated like the others.
The  `rectangle split part align` option does apply to it, but only affects the box that uses the `align` option internally (which is also the reason `\\` hasn’t the expected effect).

That means that one need to specify `align=center` and `rectangle split part align={center,…}`

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning}
\tikzset{
    umlclass/.style={
        draw=black,fill=yellow!16,rectangle split,rectangle split parts = 3,font = \ttfamily},
    umlclass -c/.style={
        umlclass,align=center,rectangle split part align={left}},         % = left,   left, left
    umlclass -r/.style={
        umlclass,align=right, rectangle split part align={left}},         % = left,   left, left
    umlclass +/.style={
        umlclass,align=center, rectangle split part align={center,left}}} % = center, left, left
\newcommand*{\umlclasscontent}{<<interface>>\\class\nodepart{second}very long attribute\nodepart{third}method()}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[umlclass -c]           {\umlclasscontent};
\node[umlclass -r] at (0,-3) {\umlclasscontent};
\node[umlclass +]  at (0,-6) {\umlclasscontent};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: THX, This is the solution that I looking for.

Comment: or is not...
try to add two atributes...

Comment: @wikingun: Yes: It works flawlessly

Comment: @Jake I have edited your answer because the `align=center` part is the right solution here (+1) but `rectangle split part align` _does_ (kind of) apply to the first text box, too.